# $(x+y)(x+1)(y+1) = 3$ and $x^3 + y^3 = \frac{45}{8}$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I've came across this problem :

> If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that 
>   $(x+y)(x+1)(y+1) = 3$ and
>   $x^3 + y^3 = \frac{45}{8}$,
>   find $xy$.

This is what I've tried so far:
$$x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) =\frac{45}{8}$$
So $$\frac{45}{8(x^2 - xy + y^2)} = \frac{3}{(x+1)(y+1)}$$
$$24x^2 - 24xy + 24y^2 = 45xy + 45(x+y+1)$$
$$24x^2 + 24y^2 - 45(x+y+1) = 69xy$$

But this doesn't seem to help. I tend to think it is just a matter of factorization and/or substitution, but I can't get it right.

A piece of advice would be apreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%28x%2By%29%28x%2B1%29%28y%2B1%29%3D3%2C+x%5E3%2By%5E3%3D45%2F8%7D) thinks it's $-1/2$.

Comment: Are you looking for a numeric answer or in terms of x and y?

Comment: @Adam numeric answer, the value of $xy$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, the whole thing is symmetric, so it would be natural to switch to the symmetric polynomials. Say, $xy=a$ and $x+y=b$. Then $(x+1)(y+1)=xy+x+y+1=a+b+1$, and $x^3+y^3=(x+y)^3-3x^2y-3xy^2=b^3-3ab$.

So $b(a+b+1)=3$ and $b^3-3ab={45\over8}$. From the first equation we have $a={3\over b}-b-1$. Plugging this into the second equation, we get $b^3-3({3\over b}-b-1)b=b^3+3b^2+3b-9=(b+1)^3-10={45\over8}$. Well, the rest is kinda obvious.

Comment: Well reasoned, Ivan!

Answer (score 3):

Expand the first equation to get

$$
x^2y+xy^2+x^2+2xy+y^2+x+y = 3
$$

Note that this can be rewritten

$$
x^2y+xy^2+(x+y)^2+(x+y) = 3
$$

Multiply this by $3$ and add to the second equation to get

$$
(x+y)^3+3(x+y)^2+3(x+y) = \frac{117}{8}
$$

Add $1$ to both sides to obtain

$$
(x+y+1)^3 = \frac{125}{8} = \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^3
$$

whereupon

$$
x+y = \frac{3}{2}
$$

This means that

$$
xy+x+y+1 = (x+1)(y+1) = 2
$$

which finally yields

$$
xy = -\frac{1}{2}
$$